# How do I create a duplicate remote branch, local branch and start checking in new changes?

Tags: git

What is the most concise and clean way of creating the following:

1. Duplicate existing master branch to a remote 'experiments' branch?
2. Setup remote to follow this new 'experiments' branch.
3. Setup local branch to link up to follow changes for remote 'experiments'

So far I have the following:

```
git checkout -b experiments
git remote add -t experiments experiments git@github.com:XXXX/YYY.git
git push --set-upstream origin experiments
```

Is this correct the set of commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git push origin master:experiment
git checkout experiment
```

2 and 3 are taken care of with the last one. You don't need any remote commands unless you have not cloned from github.

```
git remote add git@github.com:XXX/YYY origin
```

if you haven't yet then do the commands at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Adam but this does not create the branch remotely for other people to checkout the same branch.

Comment: sure it does. When you "git push origin master:experiment" that makes an experiment on the remote that others can fetch.